# Executing code before require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm in need of handling subdomains with requirejs in place.

By default requirejs will load 'data-main' from path specified in the script tag, which would be 'sub.example.com/' if use relative path instead of an absolute one.

I would like to use a top level domain length of 2, such as 'example.com', by executing a line of `document.domain = 'example.com'`. Is there any technique to ensure execution of such a line before requirejs loads anything, despite of its asynchronous nature?

Comment: It depends on how the HTML is structured, but the idea is that, since `<script>` tags are executed *sequentially* in the page, just put `<script>document.domain = 'example.com';</script>` *before* your `<script data-main="..." src="require.js"></script>`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I've actually tried it but is the order guaranteed in theory/standard?

Comment: Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script): "Scripts **without async or defer attributes**, as well as inline scripts, are **fetched and executed immediately**, before the browser continues to parse the page."

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Awesome that's the part i'm struggling to find, thank you so much :)